# Error in updating field with dynamically generated row

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have inventory form to submit inventories to database. I'm facing an issue in updating unit cost and total cost of dynamically generated rows. As you can see in snapshots below. The name of products are fetching via autocomplete jQuery.

[image]

## HTML CODE

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Product Name/Code</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Unit Cost</th>
            <th>Total Cost</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="p_scents">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input id="product_id" type="text" name="product_id[]" hidden><input id="product_code" type="text" name="product_code[]" hidden><input class="product_name form-control" id="product_name" type="text" placeholder="Type product name/code here" name="products[]" required></td>
            <td><input class="quantity form-control" id="quantity" type="text" placeholder="Quantity to Buy" name="quantity[]" required /></td>
            <td><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input class="cost form-control" id="cost" placeholder="Unit Cost" type="text" readonly /></div></td>
            <td><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input class="total form-control" id="total" placeholder="Total" type="text" readonly /></div></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="addScnt"><i class="fa fa-plus "></i> Item</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## jQuery CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents tr').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').click(function() {
        scntDiv.append('<tr>'+
        '<td>'+i+'</td>'+
        '<td><input id="product_id" type="text" name="product_id[]" hidden><input id="product_code" type="text" name="product_code[]" hidden><input class="product_name form-control" id="product_name" type="text" placeholder="Type product name/code here" name="products[]" required></td>'+
        '<td><input class="quantity form-control" id="quantity" type="text" placeholder="Quantity to Buy" name="quantity[]" required /></td>'+
        '<td><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input class="cost form-control" id="cost" placeholder="Unit Cost" type="text" readonly /></div></td>'+
        '<td><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input class="total form-control" id="total" placeholder="Total" type="text" readonly /></div></td>'+
        '<td><a id="remScnt" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span title="Delete" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>'+
        '</tr>');
        i++;
        //return false;
        $('.product_name').autocomplete({
            source:'http://localhost/Multi-Channel_Shipping/inc/auto_product.php',
            minLength:2,
            select:function(evt, ui)
            {
                // when a product is selected, populate related fields in this form
                this.form.cost.value = ui.item.cost;
                this.form.product_id.value = ui.item.product_id;
                this.form.product_code.value = ui.item.product_code;
            }
        });

        $('.quantity').keyup(function() {  
            updateTotal();
        });
        $('.cost').keyup(function() {  
            updateTotal();
        });

        var updateTotal = function () {
          var input1 = parseFloat($('.quantity').val());
          var input2 = parseFloat($('.cost').val());
          if (isNaN(input1) || isNaN(input2)) {
              if(!input2){
                    $('.total').val($('.quantity').val());
              }

              if(!input1){
                    $('.total').val($('.cost').val());
              }

          } else {          
                $('.total').val(input1 * input2);
          }
        };

        var output_total = $('.total');
        var total = input1 + input2;
        output_total.val(total);

    });

    //Remove button
    $(document).on('click', '#remScnt', function() {
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('.product_name').autocomplete({
        source:'http://localhost/Multi-Channel_Shipping/inc/auto_product.php',
        minLength:2,
        select:function(evt, ui)
        {
            // when a zipcode is selected, populate related fields in this form
            this.form.cost.value = ui.item.cost;
            this.form.product_id.value = ui.item.product_id;
            this.form.product_code.value = ui.item.product_code;
        }
    });


    $('.quantity').keyup(function() {  
        updateTotal();
    });
    $('.cost').keyup(function() {  
        updateTotal();
    });

    var updateTotal = function () {
      var input1 = parseFloat($('.quantity').val());
      var input2 = parseFloat($('.cost').val());
      if (isNaN(input1) || isNaN(input2)) {
          if(!input2){
                $('.total').val($('.quantity').val());
          }

          if(!input1){
                $('.total').val($('.cost').val());
          }

      } else {          
            $('.total').val(input1 * input2);
      }
    };

    var output_total = $('.total');
    var total = input1 + input2;
    output_total.val(total);

});
</script>
```

## AUTO_PRODUCT.PHP CODE

```
<?php

class DB
{
    const DATABASE = 'multi-channel_shipping';
    const HOST = 'localhost';
    const USERNAME = 'root';
    const PASSWORD = '';

    static private $pdo;

    static public function singleton()
    {
        if (!is_object(self::$pdo))
        {
            self::$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . self::DATABASE . ';host=' . self::HOST, 
                                    self::USERNAME, 
                                    self::PASSWORD);
        }
        return self::$pdo;
    }

    private function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function __clone()
    {
        throw new Exception('You may not clone the DB instance');
    }
}

if (!isset($_REQUEST['term']))
{
    die('([])');
}

$st = DB::singleton()
        ->prepare(
            'SELECT * ' .
            'FROM products ' .
            'WHERE (name LIKE :name) OR (code LIKE :name) ' .
            'ORDER BY name ASC ' .
            'LIMIT 0,10');

$searchProduct = '%'.$_REQUEST['term'].'%';
$st->bindParam(':name', $searchProduct, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$data = array();
if ($st->execute())
{
    while ($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'value' => $row->code." - ".$row->name,
            'cost' => $row->cost,
            'product_id' => $row->id,
            'product_code' => $row->code
        );
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);
flush(); 
?>
```

## MySQL Data

```
--
-- Table structure for table `products`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `unit` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost` decimal(25,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products`
--

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `code`, `name`, `unit`, `cost`) VALUES
(1, '4815162342', 'BAZIC 12 Dil Dil Pak', 'Packet', '0.10'),
(2, '23', 'Razer', 'Piece', '0.03');
```

***I also need to put shipping cost input field and show grand total of invoice at bottom of table.***

Comment: You can't have duplicate IDs in a page. That is invalid HTML and jQuery will only see the first match. Use classes on the added elements instead and match on those.

Comment: Why are you multiplying the inputs inside the `if`, but then adding them after the `if` is done? And why are you multiplying the numbers if they're both `NaN`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a multiple issues with the page & code, so I will try to cover what I can. `@Barmar` also spotted additional issues so will try to cover everything and suggest some improvements.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vx15mr4n/29/

**Templating:**

Rather than use text strings in code, it is easier to maintain HTML as *HTML*. The example I have provided uses a dummy script block (of type="text/template", which will be ignored by all browsers) but you can access the HTML content with `$('#template').html()`.

**Duplicate ID are invalid**

You can't have duplicate IDs in a page. That is invalid HTML and jQuery will only see the first match. Use classes on the added elements instead and match on those.

so use:

```
<a class="remScnt"
```

and

```
$(document).on('click', '.remScnt', function()
```

**Note:** you will need to sort out any other duplicate IDs too (like `product_id` and `quantity` and `cost` and `total`). Your code already uses classes for those, so just move/delete the `id` attributes.

e.g. use classes for everything:

```
    scntDiv.append('<tr>'+
    '<td>'+i+'</td>'+
    '<td><input class="product_id" type="text" name="product_id[]" hidden><input id="product_code" type="text" name="product_code[]" hidden><input class="product_name form-control" type="text" placeholder="Type product name/code here" name="products[]" required></td>'+
    '<td><input class="quantity form-control" type="text" placeholder="Quantity to Buy" name="quantity[]" required /></td>'+
    '<td><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input class="cost form-control" placeholder="Unit Cost" type="text" readonly /></div></td>'+
    '<td><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input class="total form-control" placeholder="Total" type="text" readonly /></div></td>'+
    '<td><a class="remScnt btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span title="Delete" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>'+
    '</tr>');
```

You are using a delegated event for one handler but not the others. You also need to add them for keyup (which can be combined as the code is the same):

```
$('#p_scents').on('keyup', '.quantity .cost', function() {  
    updateTotal();
});
```

**IMPORTANT: Your code here is not matching a specific row. Also use `@Barmar's` fix like this to pass the current row:**

```
$('#p_scents').on('keyup', '.quantity .cost', function() {  
    updateTotal($(this).closest('tr'));
});
```

**Update:** As `Regent` mentions below, you should not use `document` but use `#p_scents` for your delegated event handler:

```
$('#p_scents').on('click', '.remScnt', function()
```

A delegated event should be attached to the closest non-changing ancestor (if one is convenient/available). This will give a very small speed increase as it stops lower in the DOM.

I also cleaned up the event handler doing the calculations which now using temp vars, for elements relative to the row, and looks like:

```
// Update the row total of a specific row
var updateTotal = function ($row) {
    // Get the specific inputs
    var $quantity = $('.quantity', $row);
    var $cost = $('.cost', $row);
    var $total = $('.total', $row);
    var input1 = parseFloat($quantity.val());
    var input2 = parseFloat($cost.val());
    if (isNaN(input1) || isNaN(input2)) {
        if (!input2) {
            $total.val($quantity.val());
        }

        if (!input1) {
            $total.val($cost.val());
        }

    } else {
        $total.val(input1 * input2);
    }
    var total = input1 * input2;
    $total.val(total);
};
```

*Note: Without the missing data, I cannot easily test the code, but you should get the idea.*

**Grand total**

To update the grand total, you need to iterate all `.total` fields and add them to the shipping cost:

```
   var updateGrandTotal = function()
   {
       // Now update the grand total
       var grandTotal = 0;
       $('.total').each(function () {
           grandTotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
       });
       var shipping = parseFloat($('.shippingcost').val());
       $('.grandtotal').val(grandTotal + shipping);
   }
```

As you will want to update the grand total when the shipping changes, I refactored it out so it could also be called from a keyup on the shipping:

```
   $('.shippingcost').keyup(function(){
       updateGrandTotal();
   });
```

The other issue is the autocomplete (which I could not test without a real data feed):

Basically get the select event to refer to the current field's row and find the appropriate fields to update:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vx15mr4n/23/

```
   select: function (evt, ui) {
       // when a product is selected, populate related fields in this form
       var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
       $(".cost",$tr).val(ui.item.cost);
       $(".product_id", $tr).val(ui.item.product_id);
       $(".product_code", $tr).val(ui.item.product_code);
   }
```

Comment: One more thing for better code: `$('#p_scents').on('click', '.remScnt', function() {` will be slightly better (in perfomance).

Comment: @Regent: Granted and updated. The performance difference is negligible for any mouse event, but that is good practice.

Comment: @Regent: There are actually about 6 different problems with this question. Getting bored now :)

Comment: Well, yes, "practise" is more suitable word there :) I actually didn't check original code in OP, but can easily believe in 6 ones.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks for your great answer, with your solution I'm getting updated value of unit cost but it overwrites the first row and at 2nd row the Unit Cost and Total Cost are empty.

Comment: @DJ MHA: Done updating for now. Let me know if there are any more issues outstanding as there is of course no data in my example :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie "+ item" is working now, sorry I forget to change id into class. The total cost column is not working. When I add second row and select product, It update the first row's unit cost field and both cost fields at second row are empty. Snapshot is here [link](http://mp3-songs.in/sshot-1.png)

Comment: @DJ MHA: I am in the middle of a cleanup of all the code, but am having trouble emulating the data source for the autocomplete: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vx15mr4n/14/ You may want to start there as I fixed a number of additional problems and simplified the code by refactoring it a bit.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie can we have chat here [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23598/jquery)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I have updated the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vx15mr4n/17/  Total cost is not working. Please look into this, I also have upload auto_product.php on server

Comment: @DJ MHA: Just got back. There were a few typos in the previous version and I removed the extra total selector as it was invalid (not scoped to the row and not needed). The product list was blank, but I have hard-wired the item price for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/vx15mr4n/19/ Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63989/discussion-between-dj-mha-and-trueblueaussie).

Answer (score 0):

When `updateTotal()` uses `$('.quantity').val()` it gets the value of the first field with that class, not the one in the row that the user was typing in. You need to pass the row to the function. Also, since the elements are added dynamically, you need to use delegation for the event bindings.

```
$('#p_scents').on('keyup', '.quantity, .cost', function() {  
    updateTotal($(this).closest('tr'));
});

var updateTotal = function (row) {
    var input1 = parseFloat($('.quantity', row).val());
    var input2 = parseFloat($('.cost', row).val());
    if (isNaN(input1) || isNaN(input2)) {
        if(!input2){
            $('.total', row).val(input1);
        }

        if(!input1){
            $('.total', row).val($(input2);
                                }

        } else {          
            $('.total', row).val(input1 * input2);
        }
    }
    var output_total = $('.total', row);
    var total = input1 + input2;
    output_total.val(total);

};
```

Comment: with your solution add item and autocompete does not work. Could you please update your answer with complete code?